# Create table structure in postgresql from json file

Tags: json, postgresql

I would like to know if there is a way to create a table structure in postgresql using a JSON file. The story is that I exported JSON data that uses a schema from mongoDB, now I would like to create the same structure (the schema in mongo) in a table in postgresql so then I can import the data from that JSON file into it. Is there a way to do that base on the JSON file, or should I just create the table and its structure myself using the postgres JSON type and then import the data? I'm just looking for opinions, suggestions or articles that could be related to this, any help would be really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed some example data to illustrate the problem. Do you want to map `json` data into a relational structure? What're you actually trying to do?

Comment: Hi, what I want is to store json data from a json file into a postgres table using something like the copy command, I just want to knwo what's the proper way to do it.

Comment: Please, show some example data. Show a json record, and the relevant PostgreSQL table structure you want it to produce. Do you want to store it *as json*, or store it as columns of different data types (i.e. as a relation)? (Please **edit the question** and **add sample data**)